# fork() moving to the start of main()

Tags: fork

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello\n");
    fork();
    return 0;
}
```

This gives output:

```
Hello
```

Which is as expected. But if i modify the code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello");
    fork();
    return 0;
}
```

Removing, the \n gives output:

```
HelloHello
```

Why is printf called two times. Isn't the child process supposed to execute the next instruction: return 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `printf` function call places the `hello` characters into a buffer associated with the `stdout` stream. The buffer is subsequently flushed when the process exits, and that's when we see the output. You've forked before this happened, so two processes perform this buffer flushing in two separate address spaces when each of them exits. Each process has a copy of the stream, with the buffer and its `hello` contents.

When the `stdout` stream is connected to an interactive device (like a TTY on Unix), then it is line buffered. Line buffering means that the buffer is flushed whenever a newline character is output.

If we flush the buffer before `fork` (such as by printing a newline or by calling `fflush(stdout)`) then the flushing takes place in the parent process. The buffer is empty at the time the `fork`; though the child process inherits a copy of it, there is nothing left to flush in either process.

In the duplicated output case, something *is* in fact called twice. It's just not `printf`, but rather the `write` system call which sends the buffered characters to the output device.

Answer (score 1):

It's not called twice. Remember that a console-connected `stdout` is line-buffered by default. Since you haven't ended your `printf` argument with a newline, it won't go to the console yet. It'll only go to the buffer first. So `printf("Hello");` copies `"Hello"`, into the output buffer, `fork()` creates a process copy with a copy of the address space (which includes `stdout`'s output buffer with the `"Hello"` string in it) and `return 0;` returns control back to `libc`, which flushes the output buffer, but since this is happening after `fork()`, it'll happen twice -- once in the parent and once in the child, and so you get `"HelloHello"` in the final output.